# Creating Db relationships Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a new website project (part portfolio, part self-teaching) for creating and storing recipes. I've sketched out a number of tables that I think will serve as a starting point. I'm not certain the best way to relate them to each other along best practices with Entity Framework database first design. Once I have good relationships set up I would like to use this in an ASP.NET MVC application that I am also building.

1. Recipes - One recipe contains many steps, one recipe contains many ingredients, one recipe has one meal category
2. RecipeSteps
3. Ingredients - One ingredient belongs to one food group, many ingredients belong to many recipes and recipe steps
4. Food Groups - One to many with ingredients
5. Meal Categories - One to many with recipes
6. Measures

I'm using SQL DBM beta to create diagrams of the relationships

The PKs right now are datatype bigint, I don't know if this is a good idea or not.

Please reference the link below for a diagram.

https://sqldbm.com/Project/SQLServer/Share/CWVyMDaQBmjz2hb_hWrslw

Comment: Looks like the direction for the Recipe-MealCategory relationship is wrong.  For child tables the Parent table PK/FK should be the leading PK column, eg RecipeSteps should have PK (RecipeId,RecipeStepId).  I like how Ingredients is a child table of Recipe with an optional relationship to RecipeSteps. That's an elegant design, but it will require special handling in cascading changes. The relationships to FoodGroups and Measures are also reversed.

Comment: 1. Fixed Recipe - MealCategory
2. Why does RecipeSteps have a relationship to MealCategory?
3. Why is it elegant to have ingredients be a child table of Recipes with optional to RecipeSteps and why does it require special handling in 'cascading changes'?
4. I didn't think I had a relationship between food groups and measures